# How to format Python code to always return this specific length

Tags: python

Sorry if this is a bit of a noob question. But moving on..

Say at the beginning of my code I set a variable, like this:

```
TestVar = 'A6'
```

But I later want it to print out as `000000A6`

Or say it was

```
TestVar = 'C30'
```

I'd want it to print out as `00000C30`

Basically always returning it with a length of 8

The reasoning for this is I've made a general script for modding a game, (I can link if asked) and you need to put in certain values which I want to have format automatically for ease of use. For example on running it'll print

```
Item ID Here:
```

And if you put in 166 it would convert the decimal number to hex which would be A6, however in order to be usable for all values (not just ones that are 2 digits once converted) I'm trying to make it detect it's length and format it with the 0s before.

Sorry if this doesnt make sense, in a simpler way of saying this, is there a way for it to detect the length of a variable? So for example in pseudo

```
TestVar = 'C30'

    If TestVar length = 3
         print('00000'+TestVar)

Print Result: 00000C30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use string function rjust():

```
print(test.rjust(8,'0'))
```

Answer (score 1):

> Basically always returning it with a length of 8

That's what format strings do:

```
>>> print(f"{'C30':>08s}")
00000C30
```

As a sidenote, to output any number as 8-digit hex:

```
>>> print(f"{100:>08X}")
00000064
>>> print(f"{1024:>08X}")
00000400
```

See the documentation:

- for [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings) (the `f'I am an f-string'` syntax);
- for [formatting syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec) (the `>08s` and `>08X` thing).

Comment: Just to note, that's an overly complex example. Usually you don't put the string in the string, and they were asking about using a variable `TestVar`.

Comment: @PeterWood, sure - the point was to create an example that could be immediately pasted into Python and run without defining any other variables. I was actually aiming for a very simple example, but apparently ended up with a complex one:P

Comment: @ForceBru It was actually quite easy to understand, and it allows for conversion to hex much faster as opposed to the conversion table variable I had written.

Answer (score 0):

The `.zfill` string method can be used.

For example:

```
s = 'C30'
s.zfill(8)

>>> '00000C30'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

> txt = "A6"
> x = txt.zfill(8)
> print(x)

Answer (score 0):

You can use string.zfill method

for example.

```
code = '3C0'
filledCode = code.zfill(8)
```

this method filled with zero the number of digit that you pass like a parameter

Answer (score 0):

try something like this str.rjust() function

```
i = 1111
pad = '0'
n = 8

x = str(i).rjust(n, pad)
print(x)    # 00001111
```